# My Method javaKeyword keeps printing false everytime despite me typing in the words hello and gty. Is there anyway to fix this?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class StudentUtilities {
    static boolean s;

    public static int howLong (String x) {
        return x.length();
    }

    public static boolean isCharacter (String x) {
        return (x.length() > 1);  
    }


    public static boolean javaKeyword() {
        boolean b = false;
        String[] x = {"hello", "gty"};

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a word");
        String s = in.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            b = x[i].equalsIgnoreCase(s));

        return b;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(javaKeyword());
    }

}
```

My Output is

```
Type a word
hello
false
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Comment: can you provide your code of javaKeyword() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have found 'true' you must break the execution.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {

                if (x[i].Equals(s))
                {
                    b = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    b = false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the loop once you find a match, otherwise a subsequent non-match will overwrite b with false. Or, better yet, just return as soon as you find a match. Also, keywords are case-sensitive, so you shouldn't use a case-insensitive comparison:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    if (x[i].equals(s))
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is not enclosed and so the immediate statement after that only gets executed which makes it to return false always.

usethe below one,

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){ // for loop start
           if(x[i].equalsIgnoreCase(s))
            return true;

} // for loop end
```

Comment: Remove the `else return false`; that would cause a valid keyword that happens to not match the first candidate in the array to return false, when it should return true.